# Clone a PHP website on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I am trying to clone a PHP site on a my Mac through MAMP. I have copied all folder under the live `public_html` and the DB (through phpMyAdmin). I have placed them under a newly created folder under htdocs. However when I try to see it in the browser through localhost, the webpages appear blank. It throws the following error

```
Not Found 

The requested URL /cfb/en/ was not found on this server.
```

Am I missing something. Do I need to change some configuration files etc?

I have previously managed WordPress and MAMP and it worked. However I am having a tough time understanding the PHP terminology.

Comment: What is the URL you typed in the address bar ?

Comment: Maybe you have a redirect from the webroot to the path it cannot find?

Comment: What happens when you place an index.html into the htdocs folder? do you get to see the content?

Comment: I type http://localhost:8888/ and then select my subfolder which is cfb in my case and then when I hit enter http://localhost:8888/cfb/en/ it gives a blank page

Comment: I think, `.htaccess` in the folder cfb redirecting you to the folder 'en/` which is not available.

Comment: I am using MAMP, so htdocs

Comment: I m not referring `htdocs` , I am saying about the `.htaccess` file inside the `cfb/` folder

Comment: When They have index.php their index.html is just a page stating under construction. Tried placing both under htdocs one at a time. Index.html shows up however index.php goes blank page

Comment: I bet `/cfb/en` is a RewriteRule to something like `/cfb/index.php?lang=en`.

Comment: Sriraman - Its placed under cfb->blog->wp-admin->includes-> when I try searching for .htaccess What does that mean?

Comment: @DAN - They have two arabic and english version. I have recently taken over this website development not knowing that its in PHP env....:( All new to me

Comment: @Sriraman  - So how do I do it? I have to clone it on my MAC, I cannot afford to make changes on the Live website....:( I basically have to put site maps.xml on live website. However even On live website when I try placing it in en folder, it shows a blank page. I think the root folder is a problem, how do one go about finding whats the root folder? I though root folder is the one where your index.php is placed, so I tried placing it in the same folder. it does not show up.

Comment: Error in my Apache error log file is [Wed Dec 18 13:22:50 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cfb/en, referer: http://localhost:8888/
[Wed Dec 18 13:23:32 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store

Comment: Error in php error log file is Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 1
[18-Dec-2013 09:59:32 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_rows() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 4

Comment: Can someone answer????